# Results of covariance matrix in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matlab-guide

[image: ex1]
[image: ex1_2]
I'm following the example provided.I'm trying to know how did the example came up with the results of **S1** and **S1**.  I wrote in maltlab the same exact code **S1 = 4 * cov(c1) ** but the results are not the same if I did the following code, and the same for **S2** could you tell me how can I can up with the same results in example? that is 2 by 2 matrix. S1= [10 8;8 7.2], and for S2 = [17.3 16; 16 16].

```
x1=[1 2;2 3;3 3;4 5;5 5]'  % the first class 5 observations
x2=[1 0;2 1;3 1;3 2;5 3]'
m1 = mean(x1')'; 
m2 = mean(x2')'; 
m = m1 + m2; 
 Sw1 = zeros(size(x1, 1), size(x1,1)); % here Sw1 is different from example
 Sw2 = zeros(size(x1, 1), size(x1,1)); % the same for Sw2
for i = 1:size(x1,1)
    Sw1 =  Sw1 + (x1(:,i)-m1)*(x1(:,i)-m1)';
end
for i = 1:size(x2,1)
    Sw2 =  Sw2 + (x2(:,i)-m2)*(x2(:,i)-m2)';
end


Sw = Sw1 + Sw2; 
w = Sw^(-1)*(m2-m1);
```

Comment: The example of what? Page 20 of what? Could you provide a link?

Comment: I updated it right now

Comment: you forgot one value for `x2`. But you're also messing badly with the dimensions. remove all `'` (conjugation); adjust dimensions when initializing `Sw1`, `Sw2`, and fix the `for` loops: currently, they go from `1:2`. You'll want to keep the index, but change the statements inside to `Sw1 =  Sw1 + (x1(i,:)-m1)'*(x1(i,:)-m1);` (and equivalent for the other one).

Comment: Most importantly, we are talking about [`cov`ariance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html) and not [`conv`olutions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)!!!

Comment: This is not convolution. This is covariance. Please consider changing your title.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to figure out the projected line with decision boundary in my previous question. Thanks for cooperating with me.